# createReadStream and createWriteStream do not work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, graphql, apollo

I use the `Apollo/GraphQL` to write an upload process.
I can upload a file with a size of 40 MB or more on the localhost. When I run the code on the VPS, the file upload process is 100% successful but only 8 MB of the file is saved with `createWriteStream` and `createReadStream`. where is the problem from?

Result:
There is no error and no finish! Just a file with 8MB size.

**VPS tools:**

```
Nginx, Apollo/GraphQL, NodeJS
```

**Upload resolver:**

```
const uploadsResolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    singleUpload: (_, { input }, context) => singleUpload(_, input, context),
  },
};
```

**singleUpload:**

```
const singleUpload = async (parent, input, context) => {
  const { media } = input;
  // ... Read post: await Post.findOne(...)
  return media
    .then(async (uploadedFile) => {
        saveFile(uploadedFile);
      })
      .then(() => ({
        // ... return post
      }))
    .catch((error) => {
      // ERROR
    });
};
```

**saveFile:**

```
const saveFile = async (args, isImage = false) => {
  const { uploadedFile } = args;
  const { filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream } = uploadedFile;
  const pathData = createNewPath({ filename });
  const { filePath } = pathData;
 // ...
  const stream = createReadStream();
  storeFS({ filePath, stream, filename, mimetype });
};
```

**storeFS:**

```
const storeFS = (data, cb) => {
  const { filePath, stream, filename, mimetype } = data;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream
      .on('error', (error) => {
        // THERE IS NO ERROR ON VPS!
      })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
      .on('error', (error) => {
        // THERE IS NO ERROR ON VPS!
        console.log('pipe error');
        console.log(error);
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        // THERE IS NO FINISH ON VPS!
        console.log('FINISHED !!!');
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you please write the error you're facing?

Comment: There is no error and no finish! 
Just a 8MB file has been created.

Comment: There is no error and no finish! 
Just a 8MB file has been created.

Comment: I have this problem, too.